# Attempting to understand different CRC implementations

Tags: crc, crc32, crc16

Taken from IEEE 802.3,

Mathematically, the CRC value corresponding to a given MAC frame is defined by the following procedure:

> a) The first 32 bits of the frame are complemented.
>   b) The n bits of the protected fields are then considered to be the 
>          coefficients of a polynomial M(x) of degree n – 1. (The first bit
>          of the Destination Address field corresponds to the x(n–1) term and the last
>          bit of the MAC Client Data field (or Pad field if present) corresponds to the
>          x0 term.)
>   c) M(x) is multiplied by x32 and divided by G(x), producing a remainder R(x) of degree ≤ 31.
>   d) The coefficients of R(x) are considered to be a 32-bit sequence.
>   e) The bit sequence is complemented and the result is the CRC.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/crc32.txt

A big-endian CRC written this way would be coded like:

```
for (i = 0; i < input_bits; i++) {
    multiple = remainder & 0x80000000 ? CRCPOLY : 0;
    remainder = (remainder << 1 | next_input_bit()) ^ multiple;
}
```

Where is part *c) M(x) is multiplied by x^32*?  **I don't see 32 zeros appended to any number.**

Also the following piece of code make no sense to me.  The code and math don't really match up.

[Evaluating the differences in CRC-32 implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208028/evaluating-the-differences-in-crc-32-implementations)
and

```
unsigned short
crc16_update(unsigned short crc, unsigned char nextByte)
{
    crc ^= nextByte;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        if (crc & 1)
            crc = (crc >> 1) ^ 0xA001;
        else
            crc = (crc >> 1);
    }

    return crc;
}
```

What are these implementations doing? None of them really resemble the original procedure.

Even after reading the very end of this it still makes no sense:
http://www.relisoft.com/science/crcmath.html

Comment: 1. The polynomials in the description have coefficients in the finite field GF(2). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic#Effective_polynomial_representation for details on what this means. 2. The second implementation `crc16_update` is little-endian, which explains the differences between that and the first implementation (the first implementation checks `remainder & 0x80000000` and shifts left, where the second checks `crc & 1` and shifts right). 3. The multiplication by x^32 is actually the initialisation; you've only shown the update.

Comment: Great, this is making more sense.  So from the big-endian CRC, the multiplication by x^32 is the initialization to 0xFFFFFFFF at the beginning (not shown)?  Also when you say only shown the update, you meant I left out the initialization step correct?  Just want to make sure I understand.

Comment: Actually, the multiplication by x^32 might be the finalisation step, now that I think about it. But yes, the initialisation and finalisation are important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt) (also [here](http://www.repairfaq.org/filipg/LINK/F_crc_v3.html), [here](http://zlib.net/crc_v3.txt), and [here](http://www.intel-assembler.it/portale/5/A-Painless-Guide-To-Crc-Error-Detection-Algorithms/A-Guide-To-Crc-Error-Detection-Algorithms.asp) for those who will complain about link rot), in particular "10. A Slightly Mangled Table-Driven Implementation", explains well the optimization to avoid feeding an extra 32 zero bits at the end.

The bottom line is that you feed the bits into the end of the register instead of the start, which has the same effect as feeding a register-length's worth of zeros at the end.

The tutorial also shows nicely how the implementation you quoted implements the long division over GF(2).